# Getting Invalid JSON response after Laravel Project Move from 4.1 to 4.2

Tags: php, apache, laravel, dropzone.js

I'm getting an error "Invalid JSON Response from server", when uploading files using dropzone. I moved the responsible code which produces the 1 to 1 from server "dev" to server "dev1"
Here are the mayor differences in the server config:

```
 dev.hobbyathletes.com

 nginx Webserver
 php 5.3
 Laravel 4.1


 dev1.hobbyathletes.com

 Apache webserver
 php 5.4
 Laravel 4.2
```

Could the error be caused by the different server config? All dropzone areas on the dev.hobbyathletes.com are working fine. I give my response from the server simpy with:

```
 if( $upload_success ) {
     return Response::json(json_encode($success_message));
 } else {
     return Response::json('error', 400);
 }
```

This was working fine on the old system and I didn't change a thing on the new server. php configuration of the new server can be found here:
`http://krause-it-consulting.com/phpinfo.php`

Perhaps there is something wrong with the php 5.4 configuration?

**Addition:**

I was playing around a bit now with my responding function and I did some tests with ignoring the actual upload and just giving a response:

1 Attempt:

```
$errorss = "No file uploaded";
return Response::json($errorss, 400);
```

Result:

```
POST http://dev1.hobbyathletes.com/profiledz/avatar 400 (Bad     Request)
require.register.Dropzone.uploadFiles @    dropzone.js:1482
require.register.Dropzone.processFiles @ dropzone.js:1289
require.register.Dropzone.processFile @ dropzone.js:1275
require.register.Dropzone.processQueue @ dropzone.js:1268
(anonymous function) @ dropzone.js:1151
```

Second Attempt:

```
 $errorss = "tralala";
 return Response::json($errorss, 200);
```

Result:

```
 Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected token I
```

Comment: Your issue can be any number of things.  You've changed webservers, upgraded your php version, and upgraded your Laravel version in one shot.  It's going to be impossible for us to predict what the problem is.  My suggestion is to step through the code and figure out what's happening.  If while stepping through the code you come across something that isn't working like you think it should, update your question with any details you feel are relevant.

Comment: `Response::json(array $data, ...)` - it expects an array. stop giving it a string. (Also the syntax error is unrelated)

Comment: I added some more relevant information... It's related to the JSON response... What else can I do to adjust the system to a proper server JSON Response?

Comment: @Amelia Thanks, but that doesn't work. Response::json usually accepts either string or array

Comment: I downgraded now to Laravel 4.1 and now I get my usable JSON responses without changing any code... Does anyone have an explanation for that? I saw that the classes JsonResponse in folder `./vendor/laravel/framework/src/Illuminate/Http` were very different. I tried to exchange them before I downgraded, but didn't succeed. Anyway, so my project will continue to run on Laravel 4.1.*, which is fine with me. I didn't expect such problems, tbh...